# How to translate upload errors on CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, translation

I am using CodeIgniter to upload some files through a form. I know how to translate "regular" form errors (required, valid_email, etc) but I don't know how to do it with file errors (file is not allowed, file is too big, etc).

Which keys should I use in

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('KEY', 'TRANSLATION');
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

By default, [language](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html) files are typically stored in `system/language` directory. Alternately you can create a file called `upload_lang.php` inside your `application/language` folder and store them there.

```
$lang['upload_userfile_not_set']        = "Unable to find a post variable called userfile.";
$lang['upload_file_exceeds_limit']      = "The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file.";
$lang['upload_file_exceeds_form_limit'] = "The uploaded file exceeds the maximum size allowed by the submission form.";
$lang['upload_file_partial']            = "The file was only partially uploaded.";
$lang['upload_no_temp_directory']       = "The temporary folder is missing.";
$lang['upload_unable_to_write_file']    = "The file could not be written to disk.";
$lang['upload_stopped_by_extension']    = "The file upload was stopped by extension.";
$lang['upload_no_file_selected']        = "You did not select a file to upload.";
$lang['upload_invalid_filetype']        = "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.";
$lang['upload_invalid_filesize']        = "The file you are attempting to upload is larger than the permitted size.";
$lang['upload_invalid_dimensions']      = "The image you are attempting to upload exceedes the maximum height or width.";
$lang['upload_destination_error']       = "A problem was encountered while attempting to move the uploaded file to the final destination.";
$lang['upload_no_filepath']             = "The upload path does not appear to be valid.";
$lang['upload_no_file_types']           = "You have not specified any allowed file types.";
$lang['upload_bad_filename']            = "The file name you submitted already exists on the server.";
$lang['upload_not_writable']            = "The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.";
```

**METHOD 2**

You can use [Flashdata](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) after upload process.

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Yep! Upload complete');
    redirect('go_back_home');
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Uh, upload not complete! The problem is..'); // Manually check
    redirect('go_back_form');
}
```

You can also check the problem with `$this->upload->data()`. [This is a helper function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) that returns an array containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded. Here is the array prototype :

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

Comment: The first method was what I was looking for, but thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
lang:your_translation_key
```

A real example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'lang:web_name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|min_length[2]|max_length[100]');
```

Comment: I think your answer is to translate the field name, isn't it?. What I want is to translate the error message, not the field name.